# Getting blue square when pinning to dashboard

Tags: dashboard, powerbi

I am trying to create a dashboard from a Power View but when pinning it I only get a blue square.
I downloaded the lab 5 USA xlsx file from [this course](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DAT207x+1T2017/info) and I want to create a dashboard from Power View but when I click pin I only get this :

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [import Excel files with data models and Power View sheets](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/guided-learning/powerbi-learning-5-3-import-powerpivot-powerview/) using Power BI Web, Power BI will re-create them as new Reports in Power BI.

Make sure you follow through the instructions of the course.

- You should be using Power BI Web, i.e. https://app.powerbi.com, but not Power BI Desktop.
- You should use [Get Data](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/getdata/files) and [import the Excel data into Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/guided-learning/powerbi-learning-5-2-upload-excel/).
- You don't need to create your own reports or dashboards, because it's already converted automatically by Power BI. Go to the "Lab 5 - USA" report and you'll find the Power View1 report on the second tab. Please note that the first page is empty.

[image: power view]

Comment: Thank you, I already found the solution, the problem was that i was uploading the excel file and i needed to import the data